# DOS String manipulation - Replace on empty variable

Tags: batch-file

I have the following DOS commands in a batch file:

```
SET "REALM="
ECHO %REALM:/=.%

SET "REALM=Westeros"
ECHO %REALM:/=.%

SET "REALM=Westeros/"
ECHO %REALM:/=.%
```

The last two commands give me the expected results:
Westeros
Westeros.

But the first, replacing `/` for `.` on an empty variable, gives:
`/=.`

Why does this happen and how can I do this right?

Comment: What is the "expected result" when you try to replace characters from a value that does not exists?

Comment: with an undefined `%REALM%`, `ECHO %REALM:/=.%` gives me `%REALM:/=.%` (as I would expect), not `/=.` (on cmd.exe; I have no DOS available any more)

Comment: I would expect the result to be "" or nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem/feature of the parser with undefined variables.

How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?

See also [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970912/463115)

To solve this you need to test first for undefined variables like.

```
set "REALM="
if defined REALM SET "REALM=%REALM:/=.%"
echo( %REALM%
```

I used here `echo(` to avoid the output of "ECHO IS OFF" when the variable is empty.

Comment: So, as I understand it, if REALM is undefined then the command-line  processor will remove %REALM: from the command-line, leaving "/=." and continue the scan. Thus; To solve this puzzle I would have to define an empty variable, which I can't, to get the expected result.

Comment: Yes, replacing works only when the variable is defined, else it fails and you get rubbish

Answer (score 0):

If you make a`SET "REALM="`. Then `%Realm%` is undefined (without any value).

Comment: I understand the variable is undefined, but why does the replace return /=. instead of an empty string or nothing?